# How to clone yourself in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make a clone of some person that will just stand there, like basically clone myself. What is the command for this? 1.8.8 please. I do not want to clone any blocks, I want to clone myself..

Comment: Is there a video or screenshot that you've got this idea from? There's not really a command to completely clone yourself; best you could really do is put your head on a zombie.

Comment: @colorfusion Or an armor stand.

Comment: You need a mod, where did you even get this idea????

Comment: You can use the custom NPCs mod to create statues

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to clone an entity, especially a player entity, in Vanilla Minecraft. As you have probably figured out, the `/clone` command works exclusively for blocks, not entities. There is no way in vanilla to create a copy of an entity.